# iOS 9 UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification callback not called in my work

Tags: ios9, notificationcenter

In iOS 9 the following code for detecting a notification does not fire the selector method. In previous versions (e.g. 8.4) it's running fine. Does anyone know why?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{
    NSLog(@"1");
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I register the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  ...
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                       selector: @selector(handleDidBecomeActive)
                                           name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                         object: nil];
  ...
}
```

The selector handleDidBecomeActive will be called directly at the beginning of starting the app.

```
-(void)handleDidBecomeActive
{
   NSLog(@"AppDelegate: didBecomeActive");
}
```

This works in iOS9.

I tried to get the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in a class which will be created later in time (connected to the rootViewController). In this case the dedicated selector will not be called. This was working in iOS8.